# Getting closest element by id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two elements:

```
<input a>
<input b onclick="...">
```

When b is clicked, I want to access a and manipulate some of its data. A does not have a globally unique name, so `document.getElementsByName` is out. Looking into the event object, I thought `event.target.parentNode` would have some function like `getElementsByName`, but this does not seem to be the case with <td>s. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are next to each other and have the same parent, you can use the `prevSibling` property of `b` to find `a`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be able to find the element that was clicked from the [event object](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_event.asp).  Depending on your browser you might want `e.target` or `e.srcElement`. The code below is from this [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_srcelement):

   ```
   function whichElement(e) {
     var targ;
     if (!e) var e = window.event;
     if (e.target) {
       targ=e.target;
     } else if (e.srcElement) {
       targ = e.srcElement;
     }

     if (targ.nodeType==3) { // defeat Safari bug 
       targ = targ.parentNode;
     }

     var tname;
     tname = targ.tagName;
     alert("You clicked on a " + tname + " element.");
   }
   ```
2. You may then use the `nextSibling` and `prevSibling` DOM traversal functions.  [Some more information here](http://www.newearthonline.co.uk/index.php?page=article&article=284).  And yet again a w3schools reference for [XML DOM Nodes](http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_node.asp).

Answer (score 1):

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) also has nice functions to move around in the DOM. In your example something like the following would do the trick:

```
b.up().down('a')
```

And if there are is more than one a element at that level you have the power of CSS selectors at your hand to specify exactly which element you want

Answer (score -1):

Leave your plain vanilla JavaScript behind. Get JQuery--it will save you a ton of time.

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors